# Unlocking tweet size with Anaconda

Tags: go, twitter

I have trouble unlocking the length of tweets I receive using the anaconda librairy (https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda).
If tweets are too long, they're truncated and end with "...".
I would like to receive the full message.
Below is the code I'm using :

```
        trackingArray := []string{"trump", "obama"}

        anaconda.SetConsumerKey(consumerKey)
        anaconda.SetConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)

        api := anaconda.NewTwitterApi(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

        stream := api.PublicStreamFilter(url.Values{
            "track":    trackingArray,
        })

        for v := range stream.C {
            t, ok := v.(anaconda.Tweet)
            if !ok {
               logrus.Warningf("received unexpected value of type %T", v)
               continue
           }
       fmt.Print(t.Text)
       fmt.Print(t.FullText)
       }
```

Thanks to the answer below I tried t.FullText but both printing methods print exactly the same tweet (the full tweet if its length is low and a truncated tweet if its length is over 140 characters).
Thanks in advance for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean 280 char tweets? [This](https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda/blob/master/tweet.go#L16) might be what you need if so:

```
fmt.Print(t.ExtendedTweet)
```

If not perhaps give an example tweet with the problem, and check the api results yourself too with curl.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Thought it would be working but I didn't. I edited my first post above to describe my problem. The following link is useful but didn't solve my problem : https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda/pull/200